# Firefox crashes when a websocket call answered

Tags: firefox, websocket, asterisk, sipml

I'm experimenting with asterisk 13 and sipml5 on a cantos virtual machine, Everything is configured properly.

 
I use Firefox 38.0.1 to make calls from an extension to the other, and till last night everything worked just fine.

Now today when I start to call an extension and want to answer that call, firefox suddenly crashes.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What extension are you calling to, and what extension are you calling from? Is anything different from yesterday to today (updates, etc)?

Comment: I have two extensions: 1060 & 1061. call from 1060 to 1061 and vice versa worked well till yesterday, no audio issue and not even  any warning on asterisk debug. Both extensions are peer. Meanwhile I've not changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue with Google Chrome 43, I didn't want to use it but I had it coming.